# Extract MMDDYYY date from dataframe rows

Tags: python, pandas, extract

I have a dataframe where some rows of data contain a long string with a date in `MMDDYYY` format in the middle.

```
ID 
-
blah
unc.abc.155gdgeh0t4ngs8_XYZ_01252023_US_C_Home_en-us_RS_Nat'l-vs-UNC
blah
unc.abc.52gst4363463463_RST_01272023_US_C_Away_en-us_RS_Nat'l-vs-UNC
unc.abc.534gs23ujgf9d8f_UVX_02052023_US_C_Away_en-us_RS_TEST-vs-TEST
unc.abc.5830ugjshg5345s_AAA_11012023_CA_C_Home_en-us_RS_Reg-vs-HBS
unc.abc.fs44848fvs8gs82_MBB_12252023_US_C_Home_en-us_RS_Nat'l-vs-UNC
unc.abc.fe0wjv-578244fs_FFS_04222023_CA_C_Away_en-us_RS_Nat'l-vs-UNC
```

I want to use the first date that appears in that column (`01252023`) as part of the filename, so how would I extract it and set it to a variable?

Comment: I can get you started with `df[['month', 'day', 'year']] = df['ID'].str.extract('_(?P<month>\d{2})(?P<day>\d{2})(?P<year>\d{4})_')`, but I run into an issue with converting to datetime because your third row has 02352023 which looks like an invalid date of February 35th. Could you verify I'm grabbing the correct part of the string and what the correct date should be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you can use [`pandas.Series.str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) with [`pandas.Series.iat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.iat.html) to get the first matched *element/date*.

```
filename = df["ID"].str.extract(".*_(\d{8})_.*").dropna().iat[0,0]
```

Output :

```
print(filename, type(filename))
#01252023 <class 'str'>
```

Comment: I think this only works if the date first appears in position 0, but it won't always. A date might first appear in the 3rd row, or the 2nd, or the 5th. So is there a way to account for that? I've updated the original question to better reflect this.

Comment: In this case, since `.str.extract()` returns `NaN` for non matched values, then you just need to add `.dropna()`. I updated my answer.

Comment: That returns `IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0`

Comment: Working fine here with the example you shared. It seems like there is no matches at all. in your real dataset. Can you double-check to see if you missed a detail in your question ?

Comment: Hmm yeah that's odd. Seems like something with the df column headers even though it matches the code.

Answer (score 0):

Extract with `str.extract` then parse into datetime format.

```
df[['month', 'day', 'year']] = df['ID'].str.extract('_(?P<month>\d{2})(?P<day>\d{2})(?P<year>\d{4})_')
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['day'] + '-' + df['month'] + '-' + df['year'], infer_datetime_format = True)
```